# Fill an array with random non-repeating numbers (How Can I Do This Quicker)?

Tags: java, arrays

Say I wanted to fill an array with a bunch of random numbers that do not repeat. The requirements are, you must use the Random class from `java.util.Random`, you cannot use an ArrayList (I already did that using `Collections.shuffle`. You can only use a single dimensional array and any kind of loop (including if statements). In order to solve this problem, I made an array of 225 and the random numbers were not allowed to exceed 225. Here was the solution I came up with, but it does not seem very efficient. How can I do this quicker?

I filled the array with random numbers from 1 to 225. I compared each element of the array with every other element and if there was one similarity, I would restart the comparison from the 0 element. I included my source code below.

```
    int [] value = new int[225]; 
    int randnum;
    Random num = new Random();

    for (int x = 0; x < value.length; x++) // Fills array with Random Numbers from 0 to 225
    {
        randnum = (num.nextInt(225)) + 1;
        value[x] = randnum;
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < value.length; y++) // These two loops compare each value of the array
    {
        for (int z = y + 1; z < value.length; z++)
        {
            while (value[y] == value[z])
            {
                value[y] = num.nextInt(225) + 1;
                y = 0; // If the loop runs, the entire looping process starts over again.
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can't shuffle, the easiest way is to use streams:

```
int count = 225;
int[] value = new Random()
        .ints(1, count + 1)
        .distinct()
        .limit(count)
        .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean array to check which values have been added by using the number generated as your index which would give you constant lookup speed. You only have to loop the array once. Simply use the random number generated as your index to the boolean array, if the index for that number is false, then we have found a new number. If the number generated does not contain true, then we continue to generate another random number until a false value is found for the number.

```
int size = 225;
int [] value = new int[size];
boolean [] valuesCreated = new boolean[size + 1];

int randnum;
Random num = new Random();

for (int x = 0; x < value.length; x++) // Fills array with Random Numbers from 0 to 225
{
    do{
        randnum = (num.nextInt(value.length)) + 1;
    }while(valuesCreated[randnum] == true);

    value[x] = randnum;
    valuesCreated[randnum] = true;
}
```

Note that this puts the values in the array at random, however there is the smallest of smallest chances that this method will produce the values in order but the larger size array the far less likely it will do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `flag` and check it 
something like that without using HashMap or Hashset or ArrayList

```
boolean isThere = false;
for (int x = 0; x < value.length; x++) // Fills array with Random Numbers from 0 to 225
{
    randnum = (num.nextInt(225)) + 1;
    for(int i =0;i<value.length;i++){
      if(value[i] == randnum){
        isThere = true;
      }
    }
    if(!isThere){
      value[x] = randnum;
      isThere = false;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, [shmosel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50633945/315052) is the slickest solution. But, if keeping in the spirit of your original attempt, you can first populate your array with sequential members, and then use Random to implement your own shuffle.

```
int [] value = new int[225]; 
int randnum;
Random num = new Random();

for (int x = 0; x < value.length; x++) 
{
    value[x] = x+1;
}

for (int x = 0; x < value.length - 1; x++)
{
    int r = num.nextInt(225 - x) + x;
    int tmp = value[x];
    value[x] = value[r];
    value[r] = tmp;
}
```